# AWS SSO integration with G suite

Tags: single-sign-on, google-workspace, aws-sso

I want to make use of AWS SSO and integrate it to work with G suite.
I followed the official blog post - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-g-suite-as-external-identity-provider-aws-sso/

However, I'm unable to perform the user synchronization from G suite into AWS SSO via the mentioned ssosync project - https://github.com/awslabs/ssosync. There's an open issue regarding the fact that ssosync is no longer available in AWS Serverless Application Repository. I've tried to clone and build the project manually but I get a 404 error and I can't find a reason why.

I am also unable to find a way to create users/groups programmatically (didn't find anything useful in AWS SSO API reference) in AWS SSO.

Has anyone encountered this problem as well?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that does not work anymore. What about using [this one](https://github.com/slashdevops/idp-scim-sync) instead?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/awslabs/ssosync was updated to `V.2.0.0` few days ago (Dec 2022).
I installed it from [AWS Serverless Application Repository](https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home#/create/app?applicationId=arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-2:004480582608:applications/SSOSync) and it seems to work.

It requires that you configure every possible `variable` before successful execution. For variables that you don't wish to use, put `*`.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up to my attention, I'll try it and see if this works.